# Best approach to update magento 2.1.7

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.7, magento2.2

I need to update my magento version to the latest 2.2 from magento. Can any one please suggest me the best way to do this. I have soo many extensions installed on my site along with some paid extension. How I can check there compatibility?

Comment: My question title show the magento version I am currently having

Comment: BTW, it is magento 2.1.7